# Como comparar valores numericos de dos objetos (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, objeto

estoy trabajando en una función que tiene que recibir como parámetros un arreglo de objetos (pais: , continente: , población :) un string que haga referencia al continente y un valor numérico que haga referencia a la población, mediante estos parámetros la función tiene que filtrar a los paises del arreglo con el continente y la población ingresada, hasta ahí ok, el problema es que también me pide que de los paises filtrados me indique cual tiene la menor población y cual la mayor. Esto es lo que tengo hecho

```
function doubleFilter(array, cont, pobla) {
var pais = [];
var popu = 0;
var result = {
    nombres:[],
    poblaciontotal:'',
    mayor: '',
    menor: ''
};
var acumPopu
var indexPopu = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (paises[i].continente == cont && paises[i].poblacion >= pobla){
        result.nombres.push(paises[i].nombre);
        popu = popu + paises[i].poblacion;
        indexPopu.push(paises[i].poblacion, paises[i].nombre);
    };
};
result.mayor = Math.max(...indexPopu);
result.menor = Math.min(...indexPopu);

result.poblaciontotal = popu;
return result;
};
```

El problema es que mayo y menor me devuelven NaN

Aca les dejo un ejemplo del arreglo de objetos paises:

```
var paises = [
 {
 nombre: 'argentina',
 continente: 'sudamerica',
 poblacion: 40000000
 },
 {
 nombre: 'brasil',
 continente: 'sudamerica',
 poblacion: 300000000
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede facilitarte la vida utilizando funciones propias de un arreglo esta serían `filter` y `sort`

- **filter:** Permite filtrar de un arreglo los elementos que cumplan con un criterio [Más info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- **sort:** Te permite ordenar el arreglo dado un criterio específico [Más info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Con eso te propongo el siguiente código:

```js
const paises = [
  {
    nombre: "argentina",
    continente: "sudamerica",
    poblacion: 40000000,
  },
  {
    nombre: "brasil",
    continente: "sudamerica",
    poblacion: 300000000,
  },
];

const res = paises
  .filter(pais => pais.continente === 'sudamerica' && pais.poblacion === 300000000)
  .sort((a, b) => a.poblacion - b.poblacion)
  

  console.log(res);
```

En **sort** estamos definiendo que el criterio de comparación al utilizar el algoritmo de ordenamiento sea sobre la población, `a - b` te dará un order ascendente, mientras que `b - a` uno descendente